# Property 'api' does not exist on type 'MyService'. any

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms

I am following a tutorial on which we create an Angular service for sending emails from
a form using Mailthis Email API.
In the service code I get an error on the 'api' word that says
" Property 'api' does not exist on type 'MyService' ".
Any advice will be very helpfull!

My code is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {


    constructor(private http:HttpClient
              ) { }


    PostMessage(input:any){

        return this.http.post(this.api, input, { responseType:'text' }).pipe(
            map(
                (response:any) => {
                    if(response){
                        return response;
                    }
                },
                (error:any) => {
                    return error;
                }
            )
        )

    }


}
```

Comment: Please always post a link to the tutorial with questions like this. The error is very straightforward: MyService is your own class, but it doesn't have an `.api` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere you have defined api as a variable, i assume it is the endpoint you want to call, so you can define it as

```
api: string = "yourUrl";
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan!, You are very right! thanks a lot!!